# U-SQL project CI build Failed

Tags: msbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am having solution in VS-2017 which contain multiple project. And out of them one is U-SQL project and other is Class Library (For U-SQL Application) project.
But getting build error "MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified."

Comment: Can you share the detail build log on the OneDrive? (set system.debug variable value to true, then queue build and share this log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please make sure the **u-sql project to migrated to support MSBuild**.

Details about the migration, you can refer the blog [Continuous integration made easy with MSBuild support for U-SQL (preview)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2017/10/24/continuous-integration-made-easy-with-msbuild-support-for-u-sql-preview/).

Then, **use the MSBuild arguments correctly** as below:

```
/p:USQLSDKPath=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\path\to\Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.version\build\runtime /p:USQLTargetType=SyntaxCheck /p:DataRoot=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\usqlproject
```

Such as file structure for multiple projects as below:

```
root repo
    |___UsqlProj
           |___UsqlProj.sln
           |___UsqlProj
                   |___UsqlProj.usqlproj
                   |___...
           |___ClassLibrary1
                   |___...
           |___ClassLibrary2
                   |___...
           |___...
```

Then you should sue the MSbuild arguments:

```
/p:USQLSDKPath=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\UsqlProj\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.1019-preview\build\runtime /p:USQLTargetType=SyntaxCheck /p:DataRoot=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\UsqlProj
```

Comment: Hi Marina, How to check the u-sql project is migrated to support the MSBuild.

Comment: To check if the usql is migrated to support msbuild, you can search in the `.usqlproj` file to check if `<Import Project="$(AppData)\Microsoft\DataLake\MsBuild\1.0\Usql.targets" />` is replaced by `<Import Project="UsqlSDKBuild.targets" Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true' And  Exists('UsqlSDKBuild.targets')" />
  <Import Project="$(USQLSDKPath)\UsqlSDKBuild.targets" Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true' And !Exists('UsqlSDKBuild.targets') And '$(USQLSDKPath)' != '' And Exists('$(USQLSDKPath)\UsqlSDKBuild.targets')" />...` ect as the document mentions.

Comment: @RahulWagh Can you build your project successful now?

Comment: No its still failing.

Comment: @RahulWagh What's the build result if you build manually in VS? And can you share an example project which has the same error in one drive?

Comment: Marina, unfortunately I can not send the errors. But after applying the solution still we are getting "Error MSB4057: The target "Clean" does not exist in the project." On Local the solution is building without any error. But once we push into CI its get fail.

Comment: @RahulWagh What's the result if you add `/t:Clean` fir MSBuild argument in VS build task?

Comment: we have checked the "Clean" check box and that way it was not working. Will try to add /t:Clean as a part of the argument and let you know

Comment: Can you share the detail build logs by setting `system.debug` as `true`? And can you also show the screen shot for you manually built on your local machine?

Comment: This issue has been fixed by updating the USQL SDK